# Java - NotSerializableException

Tags: java, exception, serializable

I am hitting my head on the walls right now.

Here's the deal : I have made a BlockList class where I create a list of blocks. This class is Serialized and so is the Block class (And also is the class RGB I use in the Block class).

So when I try to save the list in a binary file with ObjectOutputStream, everything works just fine.

But when I try to read the file, I get this NotSerializable exception. I mean, all my classes possibly contained in the list are Serializable. Why do I even get this error ?

```
public void saveToHardDrive(){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("blocks.bk", true);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);
        oos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("ERREUR : erreur lors de la sauvegarde.");
    }
}

public void loadFromHardDrive(){
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("blocks.bk");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        list = (ArrayList<Block>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If anyone can find, I owe you for the rest of my life.

PS: even weirder : When I try to load the file, the error also mentions the save function... Even though I comment all the function.

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: vector.Block
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at vector.BlockList.loadFromHardDrive(BlockList.java:60)
at vector.main.file(main.java:184)
at vector.Controls.Controls(Controls.java:57)
at vector.main.gameLoop(main.java:111)
at vector.main.main(main.java:171)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: vector.Block
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at vector.BlockList.saveToHardDrive(BlockList.java:51)
at vector.main.file(main.java:189)
at vector.Controls.Controls(Controls.java:57)
at vector.main.gameLoop(main.java:113)
at vector.main.main(main.java:173)
```

Edit : Here's the Block class :

```
public class Block implements Serializable{
private float x;
private float y;
private float height;
private float length;
private RGB color;

public Block(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    length = 100;
    height = 100;
    color = new RGB(1, 1, 1);
}

public Block(Player p){
    setX(p.getX());
    setY(p.getY());
    setHeight(p.getHeight());
    setLength(p.getLength());
    setColor(new RGB(1, 1, 1));
}

public void render() {
    Quad.renderQuad(this);
}
```

And RGB just in case :

```
public class RGB implements Serializable{
float r, g, b;

public RGB(float R, float G, float B){
    r=R;g=G;b=B;
}
public String toString(){
    return (r*250) + ", " + (g*250) + ", " + (b*250);
}
```

}

Comment: can you add in the code for your Block class?

Comment: try declaring `list` you're reading, as `Block[]`

Comment: Comment only - You should use serialVersionUID's in your serializable classes

Comment: Can we see the delcaration of your list variable?

Comment: just for the sake of convenience - write `implements java.io.Serializable` instead of `implements Serializable`

Comment: @MarkW What is that used for ?

Comment: Are any of these non-static inner classes?

Comment: A serialVersionUID lets you deserialize a class you persisted on one version into an instance of the same class that may have changed since it was last persisted. http://www.javablogging.com/what-is-serialversionuid/

Comment: @mangusta It's running, so the list is there, and if it were a type issued, we'd see a ClassCastException.

Comment: Here is how the list is declared : 

`public class BlockList implements java.io.Serializable{
 private static List<Block> list ;
 
 public BlockList(){
  list = new ArrayList<Block>();
 }
`

Comment: You're not far from providing a complete, reproducible program. please do so by providing the *complete* code of your three classes : BlockList, Block and RGB, and a main method trying to save and load the list from a file.

Comment: Is it possible that you have two conflicting Block classes? one that is serializable and one that isnt? Try printing out the fully qualified class name of an object in your list before serializing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created the file before you made vector.Block Serializable. You have to recreate it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how am I supposed to do that.

Comment: Delete the .bk file, have saveToHardDrive() be invoked, then try loadFromHardDrive() again

Comment: How could the OP create a file containing a serialized List<Block> if Block wasn't serializable?

Comment: Well thought, that was it...

Can someone please explain what happened ?

Comment: thats what I was wondering JB, but maybe EJP knows something I dont with his 93k rep :P

Comment: @EJP please explain. I'm really curious about this.

Comment: When you do this, the NotSerializableException is encoded in the file, so you get it when you read the file.

Comment: I figured it out. I was actually not overwriting the file when saving. I was just adding lines...
Thank you gentlemen

Answer (score 0):

All classes that should be serialized, must implement the `Serializable`-Interface.

Comment: *"I mean, all my classes possibly contained in the list are Serializable. Why do I even get this error ?"*

I believe OP already addressed this.

Comment: No problem. Easy mistake to make. OP's terminology doesn't make it instantly obvious.